# Rails: Find what is the Oldest Item in a Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I am trying to find a way to get the oldest created_at value to get the oldest object in the class, so taht I can later manipulate it.

I am trying to add all the items into the array and then get the oldest value, and then convert it back by using the .where active record method to get the object created at that date.

This is what I have so far:

```
date_array=[]
      buy_requests.each do |buy_request|
        date_array << buy_request.created_at
      end
      date_array.min
```

But I feel like there are easier ways to do this.

On of the problems I am encountaring is that when I add the date to the array I no longer have the time it was created at, therfore I can no longer use .where once I get the oldest date using .min.

Thank you. Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to get the earliest timestamp and then the corresponding object, simply:

```
BuyRequests.order(:created_at).limit(1)
```

... which would benefit from an index on created_at, or maybe ...

```
BuyRequests.first
```

... if your id's are reliably assigned in first-come-first-served order.

You may want to break a tie on equal created_at timestamps with:

```
BuyRequests.order(:created_at, :id).limit(1)
```

Comment: These first two solutions infer a lot of information, don't they? The first is a very good solution, but I feel like is assumes a lot outside of OP's question. The second solution is absolutely dangerous as it completely depends on logical ordering of primary keys in your database, which we know doesn't always happen between different variations of Rails.

Comment: Yes, I agree on the ".first" method -- my memory may be playing me wrong, but I think in one sub-version of Rails 3 first just applied limit (1) on PostgreSQL queries without any ordering. Also, if you used a multi-instance database like Oracle RAC or Exadata then each instance probably has its own pool of sequence numbers and then the lowest is not necessarily the first. And if you use UUIDs for primary keys then frankly I'm not sure what first does.

Comment: I think that with respect to the OP's question in general, it would help to know what problem is being solved here. Identifying the first record in the table is in itself a simple technical matter, but I do wonder what the purpose behind it is.

Answer (score 3):

The `min_by` method does exactly what you want:

```
buy_requests.min_by(&:created_at)
```

However unless you need to load the requests anyway, it will usually be more efficient to do let the database do the sorting (assuming this is an active record model), by doing something like

```
ByRequest.order('created_at asc').first
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily use Ruby's `sort_by` method.

```
objects.sort_by { |obj| obj.attribute }
```

So for your example it would be:

```
buy_requests.sort_by { |req| req.created_at }
```

Comment: Would the make the oldest item the first of the last in the array? If sort_by does infact create an array.

Comment: Correct. The earliest items will be the "oldest".

Comment: So to get the object that was created first I would do: buy_requests.sort_by { |req| req.created_at }[0]

Comment: `buy_requests.sort_by { |req| req.created_at }.first`

Comment: See original question: "...and then convert it back by using the .where active record method to get the object created at that date." My answer is correct, because OP is trying to get the object in question, not just the `created_at` attribute.

Comment: Well there's no need to retrieve all the records and then sort them, when pushing it down to the database is going to be so much more efficient.

Comment: I don't disagree. In fact, I fully agree. But I think it's important to avoid ASSUMING things on a poster's behalf. Within the context of this question, this answer makes sense, although there are certainly more efficient ways to perform this query (e.g. push it down to the database), but that solution can't rationally be shared without inferring information outside the context of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the `#first` mehod on the Model, if all you care about is the oldest `created_at` object. I assume the `id` is are generated sequentially. ie `1, 2, 3, 4`

```
buy_requests.first
```

will get you the oldest BuyRequest instance you have.I assume the object BuyReuest is an ActiveRecord object

Comment: This is dangerous because, depending on your version of Rails (Rails 3, for example) versus other current (or future) versions of Rails, this method may not query by primary id: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/first

To be failproof, you still need to do `Model.order(:attribute).first`, which defeats the purpose of this answer.